# React initial value of createContext is used instead of provided one

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, use-context

I'm creating a Context with the boolen `isDark` inside my App. The boolean `isDark` is created with `useState` and I provide this boolean and a function to change the boolean to a `ThemeContext` to access it further down the component tree.

Down below I'm creating the `ThemeContext` with the boolean initialized to `false` and a function that just warns in the console that the initial value is being used:

```js
//ThemeContext.tsx
export type ContextType = {
  isDark: boolean
  toggleTheme: () => void
}

const ThemeContext = createContext<ContextType>({
  isDark: false,
  toggleTheme: () => console.warn('Still using initial value'),
})

export const useTheme = () => useContext(ThemeContext)

export default ThemeContext
```

Here I'm providing the theme and the functionality to change it through the `toggleTheme` function:

```js
//CustomThemeProvider.tsx
export const CustomThemeProvider: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
  const [isDark, setDark] = useState(false)

  const toggleTheme = () => {
    console.log('Change theme')
    setDark(!isDark)
  }

  const providerTheme = useMemo(
    () => ({ isDark, toggleTheme }),
    [isDark, toggleTheme],
  )

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={isDark ? darkTheme : lightTheme}>
      <ThemeContext.Provider value={providerTheme}>
        {children}
      </ThemeContext.Provider>
    </ThemeProvider>
  )
}
```

I now want to access the boolean and the `toggleTheme` function and do that through my custom hook (`useTheme`) created at the start, that just uses `useContext`:

```
//App.tsx
export default function App() {
  const { isDark, toggleTheme } = useTheme()

  return (
    <CustomThemeProvider>
      <Box flex={1} justifyContent="center">
        <Paper title="Test Title">
          <Switch onValueChange={toggleTheme} value={isDark} />
      </Box>
    </CustomThemeProvider>
  )
}
```

When I now try to switch the theme with the `Switch` component (React Native), I get the console warning that my initial function is being called. That means that my `toggleTheme` function is still the initial function `() => console.warn('Still using initial value')` even though I provided a new function, that should change the `isDark` boolean with my `ThemeContext.Provider`.
Why is my inital function still being called by the Switch instead of my provided one to change the theme?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `useTheme()` is getting the value from the default state since a Provider above it in the component tree is not found (it is at the same level).

Just wrap your application with your `CustomThemeProvider` (or a level above):

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <CustomThemeProvider>
    <App />
  </CustomThemeProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Be careful too with the `setDark(!isDark)`, you should implement it getting the previous state `setDark(state => !state)` since setting the state is deferred until re-render.

[Working Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ocve2k)

By the way, `<ThemeProvider theme={isDark ? darkTheme : lightTheme}>`, is that line a typo? If you are trying to split the Context in two (value and dispatch, which it is a nice idea), I would do it as follows:

```
const ThemeContext = createContext({
  isDark: false
});

export const useTheme = () => useContext(ThemeContext);

export default ThemeContext;
```

```
const ToggleThemeContext = createContext({
  toggleTheme: () => console.warn('Still using initial value')
});

export const useToggleTheme = () => useContext(ToggleThemeContext);

export default ToggleThemeContext;
```

```
//CustomThemeProvider.tsx
export const CustomThemeProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [isDark, setDark] = useState(false);

  const memoToggleTheme = useCallback(() => setDark(state => !state), [
    setDark
  ]);

  return (
    <ToggleThemeContext.Provider value={memoToggleTheme}>
      <ThemeContext.Provider value={isDark}>{children}</ThemeContext.Provider>
    </ToggleThemeContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

[Working Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-qkzgkw) memoizing the component which dispatches the action because otherwise it will be re-rendered by the `App` component when the `theme` changes.

By doing that only the component that uses the value will be re-rendered.

Let me link you an article I wrote the last day about everything related to React Context, including optimization [React Context, All in One](https://dev.to/javmurillo/react-context-all-in-one-54ck)

Comment: It worked great. I'm going to have a read over the article. And my line with the `ThemeProvder` was not a typo because that is a Provider by ´@Sopify/restyle´ which I use to theme my App. So I just change the provided theme based on the isDark boolean.